# Are remapped Xbox buttons stored on the controller?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

Via the [Xbox Accessories](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/xbox-accessories/9nblggh30xj3?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) app, it appears that you can remap the buttons on your Xbox one controller (*awesome!*).

**Question:** Would the newly remapped button scheme be stored directly on the controller? Or on the Xbox/PC? In other words, if I remap the buttons, and then use the controller with a different Xbox/PC, will my remapped button scheme come along with me to the new system? Is the behavior any different with the Elite controller?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it stores any information on gamepad itself.

You can imagine something like this:

- Standard: Xbox Game Pad A > Receiver > Xbox Console > Yeap that's an A.
- With Xbox Accessories app: Xbox Game Pad A > Receiver > Wait a second I should check my own profile. Nope it's not A, it's B (says the app) > Xbox Console > Yeap that's a B!

It's just a profiler app. But let's say you're using another console with Xbox Accessories not installed, how can it manage this signal binding?

Answer (score 0):

For a classic Xbox controller, it appears not.

But, according to [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/xbox-accessories/9nblggh30xj3?activetab=pivot:overviewtab):

> With an Xbox Elite Wireless Controller or Xbox Adaptive Controller, you can **save multiple profiles to your controller**, so they’re ready to use whenever you’re ready to game.

This seems confirmed by [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/xboxone/comments/dysn5c/can_you_save_xbox_elite_controller_profiles_xbox/):

> Yes, the profiles are **saved in the controller** so they'll stay the same across platforms.

And makes sense, because you can't even start the app on PC without a connected controller.

Also Microsoft Store states that "the app allows you to update firmware for your controller", so this should be how the app actually works.